# Why doesn't this Hello World X11 code run on NetBSD?

Tags: x11, netbsd

I am on a brand new 5.1 NetBSD box.

I copied the "Hello World" code from here [`rosettacode.org`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#Xlib)

The code compiles with this command:

```
cc -I /usr/X11R7/include -L /usr/X11R7/lib -lX11 helloworld.c
```

When I run `a.out`, I get the following error:

```
Shared object "libX11.so.6" not found
```

I confirmed that `/usr/X11R7/lib/libX11.so.6` does exist.

ldd output:

```
./a.out:
    -lX11.6 => not found
    -c.12 => /usr/lib/libc.so.12
```

How do I properly link against X11 on NetBSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official NetBSD answer is to [use RPATH](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/elf.html#elf-rpath). Crazy.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am still a C novice.  I had come across that link before posting my question, but wasnt quite sure what I was looking at.  Appending -R /usr/X11R7/lib worked, thanks man!